# CRM 4.0 reliant picklists javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, attributes, crm, picklist

I am currently working on a CRM 4.0 project where I have created picklist A with 34 values and picklist B with 132 values.

Picklist B is dependent on the value selected in picklist A which range from between 2 and 14 values of the total 132.

Previous developers wrote Javascript which defines each picklist value and sets disabled to true or false, but this is going to be messy with 132 values - see below..

```
var picklist = document.getElementById("picklist_b");
if(crmForm.all.picklist_a.value==2)
{
crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("picklist_b", 2);
picklist[1].disabled = false;
picklist[2].disabled = false;
picklist[3].disabled = false;
picklist[4].disabled = true;
picklist[5].disabled = true;
picklist[6].disabled = true;
```

Do you have any ideas on a better way to do this?

Many Thanks...

Comment: any chance your customer is considering an upgrade to a newer CRM version?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you will have to tell the system what values you want to appear and when which will take some manual work. To give some structure to your work you could lay it out like this:

**1)** Register an onChange() event against Picklist A and get its value:

```
var picklistA = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("picklistA").getValue();
```

**2)** Get all of the available options from Picklist B (to save you typing):

```
var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("picklistB").getOptions();
```

**3)** Now remove all options from Picklist B:

```
var picklistBControl = Xrm.Page.getControl("optionset");
picklistBControl.clearOptions();
```

**4)** Define the relationship between Picklist A values and Picklist B values (example):

```
var mapping = [
    {
        parent: 550000000,
        children: [
            660000000, 660000001
        ]
    },
    {
        parent: 550000001,
        children: [
            660000003, 660000004
        ]
    }
];
```

**5)** Get the new options that you want by comparing the value of Picklist A against the `mapping` array:

```
function getNewOptionValues(picklistA) {
    var newOptionValues = function (picklistA) {
        return mapping.forEach(function (m) {
            if (m.parent == picklistA) {
                return m.children;
            }
        });
    }(picklistA);

    return newOptionValues;
}
```

**6)** From the values of the new options you want, build them into valid objects:

```
function buildNewOptions(oldOptions, newOptionValues) {
    var newOptions = [];

    for (var option in oldOptions) {
        for (var newOption in newOptionValues) {
            if (option.value == newOption) {
                newOptions.push(option);
            }
        }
    }
    return newOptions;
}
```

**7)** Finally, add the new options to Picklist B:

```
function addNewOptions(newOptions, childControl) {
    for (var newOption in newOptions) {
        childControl.addOption(newOption);
    }
}
```

---

Some of this code may not work in CRM 4.0, I can't remember. I hope this helps nonetheless. Also note that the functions in points 5, 6 and 7 need to be invoked (if you're not familiar with JavaScript).

Comment: Xrm methods were introduced with CRM 2011